# Why nonsymmetric orthogonal matrices are not orthogonally diagonalisable?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

It is well known that a real matrix is orthogonally diagonalizable if and only if it is a symmetric matrix. However, the condition for orthogonal eigenvectors for a square matrix $A$ is $A^TA=AA^T$. Any nonsymmetric orthogonal matrix will also satisfy this criterion then why it is not orthogonally diagonalizable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can't be expected to happen over the reals: orthogonal matrices have real entries, so a purported orthogonal diagonalization $QOQ^T$ of an real othogonal matrix $O$ by the real orthogonal matrix $Q$ would yield a real diagonal matrix with real eigenvalues for $O$. But orthogonal matrices typically have complex eigenvalues. You can see this in the $2\times2$ case $O=\begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta&\sin\theta\\-\sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{pmatrix}$. It is easy to check that its eigenvalues are $\cos\theta\pm i\sin\theta$.

Note that  the conjugation $QDQ^T$ of a  diagonal matrix $D$ by an orthogonal matrix $Q$ is symmetric.  All non symmetric orthogonal matrices  are counterexamples to what you want.

Comment: Is it true that any nonsymmetric orthogonal matrix must have complex eigenvalues?  Or eigenvectors?

Comment: They typically do, but there are exceptions: the identity matrix for example , and its negative, are both orthogonal and have real eigenvectors. But the matrix $O$ in my answer has characteristic polynomial $\lambda^2-2\cos\theta \lambda+1$, whose roots are $\cos \theta\pm i\sin\theta$.   For most values of $\theta$ these are complex.

Comment: Identity is a symmetric matrix.  I was thinking about nonsymmetric.  Also the well known Theorem says that a real matrix is orthogonally diagonalizable if and only if it is symmetric.

Comment: I have edited my answer.  If this does not answer the question you think you want to ask, post a new one.